# How do we sort faster using unix sort?

Tags: unix, sorting

We are sorting a 5GB file with 37 fields and sort it with 5 keys. The big file is composed of 1000 files of 5MB each.

After 190 minutes it still hasn't finished.

I am wondering if there are other methods to speed up the sorting. We choose unix sort because we don't want it to use up all the memory, so any memory based approach is not okay.

What is the advantage of sorting each files independently, and then use -m option to merge sort it?

Comment: Are you sorting the 5 files by 5 background processes ?

Comment: if you have divided the 5 GB file into 5 files each of 1000 MB , you can start the sort on each file with different jobs . So you might save time making them  background processes

Comment: hmm...I will think about it...

Comment: Is it viable to import the data into a database, sort it there, and then export it to file again?

Comment: `sort` is usually very conservative in its memory usage and diverts to an external sort algorithm quite soon. Your particular version may accept an option to increase its RAM buffer size (i.e, GNU sort uses `-S` for that).

Comment: I've done this in the past: http://blog.mafr.de/2010/05/23/sorting-large-files/ it worked well for me.

Comment: I think I've answered your question @lamwaiman1988 :)

Answer (score 63):

Buffer it in memory using `-S`. For example, to use (up to) 50% of your memory as a sorting buffer do:

```
sort -S 50% file
```

Note that modern Unix `sort` can sort in parallel. My experience is that it automatically uses as many cores as possible. You can set it directly using `--parallel`. To sort using 4 threads:

```
sort --parallel=4 file
```

So all in all, you should put everything into one file and execute something like:

```
sort -S 50% --parallel=4 file
```

Comment: Thanks. This is useful. `sort` "claimed" to be CPU-bound to one core, but was using less than 10 MB memory to sort GBs of text: certainly that wasn't its best. (sort 8.21, Linux 3.13.0-29-generic.) Now it's using 12 GB of RAM and 8 cores, I'm sure it will be faster. ;-)

Comment: Awesome! Sounds like you are comparing bytes to the max now =D

Comment: This is a great answer. This sped up my multi-GB sort by a few orders of magnitude.

Comment: Great answer! Excellent!

Comment: Wish I could make these the default values... (-S80% --parallel num_cpu-1)

Comment: Are we sure that -S means total ram used for buffer, regardless of the number behind parallel? For example, if I say --parallel 8, I am happy if the 8 "things" (I don't know if these are actually threads or processes) use 50% of RAM in total. But if each "thing" uses 50%, I will run out of RAM quickly. I recently had a few mysterious memory failures on my host that I did not fully understand yet.

Comment: never mind, I found this from the official doc: https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#sort-invocation 
For -S, "this option affects only the initial buffer size. The buffer grows beyond size if sort encounters input lines larger than size." 
For parallel, "Note also that using n threads increases the memory usage by a factor of log n."

Answer (score 6):

1. Divide and conquer. A sort of N files can be faster if you first sort each of the N
   files (and use different CPUs on multiprocessors). Then the files need only be merged (e.g. `sort -m files
   ...`; -m is POSIX and should be supported by all sorts of sorts; pun intended). Sorting each file consumes much less resources.
2. Give sort a fast /tmp directory
3. Thinking outside the box: make the process creating the files sort the data right away
4. Brute force: Throw more hardware (memory, CPU cycles) at the problem :-)
5. Get informed about the concept of [external sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sort)

Comment: I would question most of that. External sort time is dominated by I/O, not by CPU. Once you get into multilevel merging, the number of runs produced and the number of merge passes totally dominates, and this happens at disk speeds, not CPU speeds. And disks aren't multi-core.

Comment: By default, `sort` splits large files into small files and sorts them individually, and then merges them. So there is no need to do it manually.

Answer (score 5):

The Unix sort isn't the fastest sort out there by any manner of means. It uses a strange implementation that can easily be outrun over data sets that are large enough to require multiple merge passes, as yours clearly does. I would have a look around for a replacement. You could even consider loading the file into a database: you might get better performance that way, and you would certainly have the data in a more convenient form afterwards.

For completeness, the main issue is the bucket sort itself. It's quick for small data sets, although not as quick as Quicksort, but it produces twice as many runs as replacement selection would. Once you get into multilevel merging, the number of runs and hence the number of merge passes totally dominates the CPU-bound distribution phase.

I implemented a sort-merge package for COBOL many years ago, straight out of Knuth vol. III, with distribution via replacement selection, and balanced merging with dummy runs. On large enough data sets it easily outperformed the Unix sort, with an increasing gradient as N increased, and 'large enough' wasn't all that large given disk sizes of those days.

Answer (score 5):

One of the main time consumers with Unix `sort` is finding the keys; that is anything but the simple comparison operation that you tend to see in simple sorting exercises.  Even finding one of the keys is quite a slow process.

So, one way to speed things up is to make it easier for the `sort` to find the keys, by preprocessing the file so that the 5 keys you mention are at the front of each line, then sorting the data (maybe using the splitting and merging operations suggested by others) and then removing the keys.

For example, if you have colon-separated fields, and the sort keys are 1, 3, 7, 10, 12, and they're all regular alphabetic sorts, then you might use:

```
awk  -F: '{print "%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", $1, $3, $7, $10, $12, $0; }' monster-file |
sort -t: -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4 -k5,5 |
sed 's/^[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*:[^:]*://'
```

You might even be able to do without the five `-k` options and simply run `sort -t:`.  In fact, you can probably arrange to use a different delimiter altogether (maybe a control character such as ^A) to simplify the code.  You separate the key fields from the main record with this alternative character:

```
awk  -F: '{print "%s:%s:%s:%s:%s^A%s\n", $1, $3, $7, $10, $12, $0; }' monster-file |
sort -t$'\001' |
sed 's/^[^^A]*^A//'
```

This uses a `bash`-ism ([ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)) in the `$'\001'` argument to `sort`; the `^A` items in the `awk` and `sed` scripts are what you get from typing <kbd>Control-A</kbd>, though you could also arrange for the `bash` notation to provide the character too:

```
awk  -F: '{print "%s:%s:%s:%s:%s'$'\001''%s\n", $1, $3, $7, $10, $12, $0; }' monster-file |
sort -t$'\001' |
sed "s/^[^$'\001']*$'\001'//"
```

(*Warning: untested scripting.*)

There's a fascinating article on re-engineering the Unix sort ('Theory and Practice in the Construction of a Working Sort Routine', J P Linderman, AT&T Bell Labs Tech Journal, Oct 1984) that's not readily available (I've not found it on the Internet despite several attempts to search for it), that describes how `/bin/sort` was improved.  Even after all the improvements, one of its recommendations for complex sorts was exactly along these lines.

Comment: I remember the paper well. Like sort(1) itself, it focusses on the wrong end of the problem. All this is really only true during the distribution phase. After that it's all I/O bound anyway. See the discussion in my answer.

Comment: Well, the balance of performance between memory and disk I/O has changed since then, so you may be right that nowadays it is only the disk I/O that matter.  I've not conducted relevant experiments recently — when I did, it was accurate (but that was probably in the last millennium, in the days of slow single-core CPUs).

Comment: I didn't say anything about 'nowadays'. It was true in 1984 as well :-) That's when I was wrote my package. It was even more true in 1977 when I wrote my first one, and truer still in the 1960s when it was all done on tapes and all the theory was worked out.

Answer (score 3):

Split the file into smaller files, sort the smaller files using many cpus, merge back together.

I've done this in the past:

```
split -l5000000 data.tsv '_tmp';
ls -1 _tmp* | while read FILE; do sort $FILE -o $FILE & done;
sort -m _tmp* -o data.tsv.sorted
```

it worked well for me.

Example performance on 20M line file :

```
joshua10.13> wc randn20M.csv 
 20000000  20000000 163197726 randn20M.csv
joshua10.14> cat par_srt.sh 
#!/bin/bash

split -l5000000 randn20M.csv '_tmp';
ls -1 _tmp* | while read FILE; do sort $FILE -o $FILE & done;
sort -m _tmp* -o data.tsv.sorted
joshua10.15> time ./par_srt.sh 
1.516u 0.344s 0:05.85 31.6%     0+0k 0+522584io 0pf+0w

joshua10.16> time sort randn20M.csv -o dataone.sorted
21.461u 0.596s 0:24.08 91.5%    0+0k 0+318752io 0pf+0w
```

Remark: if you are I/O bound (e.g. a 20g file with 20 lines) then this won't help at all.

Comment: Don't you need a wait in there before the final sort?

Answer (score 3):

Another optimization:

```
LC_ALL=C sort ...
```

And if, for example, you have csv-file with quoted numbers and need to sort numerically on col2, col1, then use:

```
-t',' -k2.2,2n -k1.2,1n
```

And to pre-sort files before merging (sort -m) them into a single output-file, use

```
LC_ALL=C ls -1 *.csv |
  xargs -d'\n' -n1 -P4 -I'{}' sort ... -o '{}' '{}'

LC_ALL sort -m --parallel=20 --buffer-size=30% ... -o sort.out *.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

`parsort` is a part of GNU Parallel. It chops files into smaller parts, sort these in parallel and does a merge.

It uses GNU Parallel and GNU sort, but outperforms `sort --parallel` by 3x on a 64 core machine.